# Google Tag Manager breaks Next.js Link

Tags: next.js

I'm using GTM for analytics on a Next.js site, and I've found that GTM breaks Next.js `<Link>` functionality.

Specifically, clicking on a `<Link href={...}><a>text</a></Link>` will do a full page refresh. I suspect GTM is doing something to the `<a>` tags in order to track user activity.

I've reproduced the issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/q88owlwn7q

- To check when Next.js dynamic navigation is working, I've added some `Router.events.on` callbacks in `./src/navigation.js` that call `console.log` with the event that's been fired.
- To either include GTM or not, add/remove `<GtagScript/>` from where it currently is in `./pages/document.js`

Notice the following:

- When GTM is excluded, Next.js works properly.
- When GTM is included, dynamic navigation is broken (full refreshes happen instead).

For quick reference GTM is included via the following:

```
<script async
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
    />

<script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}');
        `}}
</script>
```

(full example available in the CodeSandbox link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent this from happening, I had to get `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=...` to load on the client-side, and after the component has mounted.

1. To load on client-side, insert the `<script ...` tag in your `_app.js` file.
2. To load it after the first render, have loading depend on a state variable that is updated when the component has mounted (and rendered once). So in either your `componentDidMount` or in your `useEffect` hook.

e.g.

```
{loaded && <script ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this a bit simpler for yourself there is a nice plugin called react-gtm-module that takes the pain of config away from this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module